# one.('click') reset after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code. I make first lines here as comment, because they are not important in my question, just for structure. I have click event, after click on td I have input field with text in it. I set focus at end of text. But when I have made click, I want to remove focus , so that I can click in middle position of name, and cursor will be there. It works when it is one.('click'), but i need to do it multiple times, so one click works just for one time.

```
$('td').on('click', function() {    
    //val = $(this).text();
    //console.log(val);
    //rowid = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    //realclass = $(this).attr('class');
    //$("tr").filter("#" + rowid).find("td").filter("." + realclass).find("span").hide(); //hide td->span field..
    //$("tr").filter("#" + rowid).find("td").filter("." + realclass).find("input").show();//..and show input field
    //get focus on end of input val
    SearchInput = $("tr").filter("#" + rowid).find("td").filter("." + realclass).find("input");
    strLength = SearchInput.val().length;
    SearchInput.focus();
    SearchInput[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, strLength);
});
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle to reproduce this? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: surely `$("tr").filter("#" + rowid)` can just be `$("#" + rowid)`

Comment: Yes. I missed this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that clicking on the input itself also triggers the click event on the encompassing `<td>` element (due to event propagation or "bubbling"), which you don't want to happen. To prevent that you want to call the `event.stopPropagation()` function when handling click events on the input:

```
$('td input').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: That works, unless the OP also wants this behaviour the first time the input is clicked, but I guess that's not the case.